# Angularfire2 - not saving result data

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angularfire, angularfire2

I think this is because I don't actually know how to do what I want properly. Basically I'm saving an association between a user and a school (also a user) and in the new document want to pull some image urls from the school user. My queries to do this both return undefined...

Basically I then want to save those image urls in another document which I'll use.

The result is printed to the console fine....

```
private addUserSchool(userId: string, school: any) {

    const concatId = this.concatIds(userId, school.uid);

    const userSchoolsRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`userSchools/${concatId}`);
    const schoolRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`users/${school.uid}`);
    let schoolImageURL;
    let schoolImageLogoURL;

    if(school.active) {

        schoolRef.valueChanges().subscribe(result => {
            console.log(result)
            return schoolImageURL = result.schoolImageURL;
        });
    }

    schoolRef.valueChanges().subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result)
        return schoolImageLogoURL = result.schoolImageLogoURL;
    })

    // create model from this.
    const data = {
        userId: userId,
        schoolId: school.uid,
        active: school.active ? school.active : false,
        activeSchoolImageURL: schoolImageURL ? schoolImageURL : null,
        activeSchoolLogoURL: schoolImageLogoURL ? schoolImageLogoURL : null
    }

    return userSchoolsRef.set(data, { merge: true })
}
```

Comment: With AngularFire2, `subscribe` is asynchronous and the values for `schoolImageURL` and `schoolImageLogoURL` will be assigned **after** the call to `set` is made.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, the values are not yet available when you make your `set` call.

You can use another rxjs operator to execute the `set` when the values of the first call are available:

```
private addUserSchool(userId: string, school: any): any {

    const concatId = this.concatIds(userId, school.uid);

    const userSchoolsRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`userSchools/${concatId}`);
    const schoolRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`users/${school.uid}`);

    schoolRef.valueChanges()
        .pipe(
            take(1),
            switchMap(schoolData => {
                const data = {
                    userId: userId,
                    schoolId: school.uid,
                    active: school.active,
                    activeSchoolImageURL: school.active ? schoolData.schoolImageURL : null,
                    activeSchoolLogoURL: schoolData.schoolImageLogoURL
                };
                return of(userSchoolsRef.set(data, { merge: true }));
            })
        )
        .subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this, it seems like a really clean way of doing it, I'll post what I came up with in the end.